# xsl file using properties.xml file in order to transform an xml file into the xml file with custom tags defined in properties.xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, properties

If you store the properties file in XML format, for instance

```
<Properties>
    <Property value="abc">ABC1</Property>
    <Property value="...">...</Property>
</Properties>
```

then we can use xslt to process both(properties,input) XML files and replace abc elements(of input xml file) with ABC1(of custom output xml file) ones, etcetera.

for example consider my below input xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Content>
          <abc>xxx
                 <def>zzz
                    <ghi>ccc</ghi>ttt
                     <dynamic val="hello" xmlns="http://abc.com" />
                      world
                     <dynamic val="hi" xmlns="http://abc.com" />
                       <dynAttr>
                         <dyn value=123 />
                         <dyn value=222 />
                       </dynAttr>
                         <lmn>data</lmn>

                   </def>
                </abc>
         </Content>
```

with Properties file consisting of a property defined for each tag of input xml file,if no property defined for that input xml file tag then transformed xml tag has the same tag name to that of input xml file tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
             <Property value="Content">CONTENT12</Property>
             <Property value="abc">ABC1</Property>
             <Property value="def">www</Property>
              <Property value="ghi">yyy</Property>
             <Property value="dynamic">Dynamic1</Property>
             <Property value="dynAttr">DynAttribute</Property>
</Properties>
```

using xslt and writing an xsl file which refers the properties xml file and when applied on the given input xml file and results in the transformed xml file as shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

                <www>zzz
                    <yyy>ccc</yyy>ttt
                     <Dynamic1 val="hello" xmlns="http://abc.com>hello</Dynamic1>
                      world
                     <Dynamic1 val="hi" xmlns="http://abc.com>hi</Dynamic1>
                       <DynAttribute>
                         <dyn>123</dyn>
                         <dyn>222</dyn>
                       </DynAttribute>
                         <lmn>data</lmn>
                   </www>
if the above code is my requirement then what must be the relative xpath expression in your answer <xsl:template match=" ">
```

Comment: @Maestro13 : hi do you have any solution for the above above question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example file is not well formed, but if you fix that, and your property file is prop.xml, this should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:variable name="n" select="name()"/>
 <xsl:variable name="new">
  <xsl:for-each select="document('prop.xml')">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="key('n',$n)">
     <xsl:value-of select="key('n',$n)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:element name="{$new}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="n" match="Property" use="@value"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your question does not say what namespace renamed elements should be in. the above code always puts them in no-namespace. If you want them to be in the same namespace as the original change the xsl:element line to

```
 <xsl:element name="{$new}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
```

The most flexible alternative would probably be to specify both the local name and namespace uri in the properties file.

*update*

If as noted in the comments and the updated answer you want to preserve namespaces and only process the `def` element then a minor modification as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//def"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:variable name="n" select="name()"/>
 <xsl:variable name="new">
  <xsl:for-each select="document('prop.xml')">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="key('n',$n)">
     <xsl:value-of select="key('n',$n)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:element name="{$new}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="n" match="Property" use="@value"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But when we use copy-of or any copy tag I will also get another namespaces associated with input xml file rather than required namespaces can you suggest any alternative?

Comment: the only place I used copy-of above is to copy attributes. You did not give any indication of a need to change attribute names, or for that matter if you have namespaces in your source file, how you want to match the element names to your property file (using namespace URI and ignoring prefixes or, as above ignoring namespace uri and matching on names including prefixes) if you edit your question giving an indication of namespace use I'll modify my answer if it doesn't still fit.

Comment: @ David Carlisle:Thanks,the code is working fine but may i know <xsl:template match="*"> what exactly it matches. This means that it matches each and every node of input xml.

Comment: @ David Carlisle : what if i want to match from specific node of input xml document and try building my output xml with the root node as the matched node .ie., what should be the relative xpath expression if i  want <www> as root node excluding its parent nodes CONTENT12 and ABC1 from output. I guess it may be like  <xsl:template match="def/*">

Comment: @ David Carlisle : please refer to  the edited question and can you answer me . I am very much eager to know the answer.

Comment: i still don't see why the code posted doesn't meet your requirement

Comment: the code is upto the mark, no queries on that. I edited the question according to my new requirement. I think there might be a slight change in the xpath in your existing code inorder to meet my new requirement.Can you please suggest that.Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your response but what Iam currently dealing with is to get some part(sub-tree) of the input xml file and replace their nodes with their respective properties. You can see how my output should look like in my edited question. So for the required ouput what exactly should be the xpath expression in <xsl:template match=" ">

Comment: Pardon me if Iam wrong your xslt code is not working.Can you recheck it.xsl:apply-templates select="//def" thing is not working.

Comment: works for me I get `<www>zzz
                    <yyy>ccc</yyy>ttt
                     <Dynamic1 xmlns="http://abc.com" val="hello"/>
                      world
                     <Dynamic1 xmlns="http://abc.com" val="hi"/>
                       <DynAttribute>
                         <dyn value="123"/>
                         <dyn value="222"/>
                       </DynAttribute>
                         <lmn>data</lmn>

                   </www>`

Comment: Can you try answering the question in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10072845/1245910