# need to transform an xml file into another xml using xslt whose xsl file uses a Properties.xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, properties, mapping

Consider my input xml file as below

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <com xsi:schemaLocation="http://do.way.com/sales/Amb
           http://do.way.com/temp/sales/ale/ax.xsd" 
           xmlns:w="http://do.way.com/sales/W" 
           xmlns="http://do.way.com/sales/Amb" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:wire="http://do.way.com/sales/Wire">

    <content>
      <wire:wire>
        <wire:sI>

          <w:aH>
          <text>Ccc  <dynamic name="C_R_N"/>: More</text>
          <w:contact value="false"/>
          </w:aH>

          <w:page>
            <nL>Please call us</nL>
          </w:page>

          <w:body>
            <text> C R N: <strong>
           <dynamic name="C_R_N"/></strong>
            </text>
          </w:body>

          <w:body>
            <text>
              RE: <dynamic name="D_C_P"/> <dynamic name="M_C_O"/>
            </text>
          </w:body>

          <w:body>
            <text>
              In order <strong>
                <dynamic name="M_D_D"/>
              </strong>, we need some information.
            </text>
          </w:body>

          <w:body>
            <text>
              <strong>
                Please call us <dynamic name="C_P_D_N"/>.
              </strong> Our hours <ul class="nested">
                <li>
                   Monday - Friday, 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_S_Hour"/> am - 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_E_Hour"/> pm; Saturday, 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_S_Hour"/> am - 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_E_Hour"/> pm.
                </li>
                       </ul>
            </text>
          </w:body>

          <w:body>
            <text>
              Thank you for your  action. .
            </text>
          </w:body>


          <w:body>
            <text>
              <dynamic name="C_D_N"/>
            </text>
          </w:body>


          <w:TextAndImage>
            <text>
             <dynamic name="C_S_N_D"/>            
            </text>
          </w:TextAndImage>

          <w:dynamicNames>
            <w:dynamicName value="LOW"/>
            <w:dynamicName value="Env"/>
          </w:dynamicNames>

          </wire:sI>
        </wire:wire>

          </content>
          </com>
```

the required xsl file which transforms the above input xml file refers to a Properties.xml file which has the respective transformed tags(values) for the input xml tag elements(keys) given below
          Properties.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            <Properties>     
            <Property value="w:aH">aHe</Property>
           <Property value="w:contact">contact1</Property>
           <Property value="w:page">pageH</Property> 
           <Property value="w:body">bodyP</Property>
           <Property value="w:TextAndImage">textAndImage1</Property>
           <Property value="w:dynamicNames">dynamicNames1</Property>
           <Property value="w:dynamicName">dynamicValName</Property>
         </Properties>
```

and my transformed xml  looks like

```
    <Content xsi:schemaLocation="id:d1234 http://abc:10/w/g/B/System/abc.xsd" 
 xmlns="id:d1234" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


     <aHe>
      <text>Ccc  
             <dynamic name="C_R_N" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
                  C_R_N
            </dynamic>
        : More
    </text>
      <contact1>false</contact1>
      </aHe>

      <pageH>
        <nL>Please call us</nL>
      </pageH>

      <bodyP>
        <text> C R N: <strong>
       <dynamic name="C_R_N" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      C_R_N
     </dynamic>
      </strong>
        </text>
      </bodyP>

      <bodyP>
        <text>
          RE: <dynamic name="D_C_P" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
              D_C_P</dynamic>
             <dynamic name="M_C_O" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">M_C_O</dynamic>
        </text>
      </bodyP>

      <bodyP>
        <text>
          In order <strong>
            <dynamic name="M_D_D" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> M_D_D </dynamic>
          </strong>, we need some information.
        </text>
      </bodyP>

      <bodyP>
        <text>  Please call us 
          <strong>
           <dynamic name="C_P_D_N" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">C_P_D_N</dynamic>.
          </strong> Our hours <ul class="nested">
            <li>
               Monday - Friday, <dynamic name="DST_M_F_S_Hour" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">DST_M_F_S_Hour</dynamic> am - <dynamic name="DST_M_F_E_Hour" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">DST_M_F_E_Hour</dynamic> pm; Saturday, <dynamic name="DST_M_F_S_Hour" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">DST_M_F_S_Hour</dynamic> am - <dynamic name="DST_M_F_E_Hour" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              DST_M_F_E_Hour</dynamic>pm.
            </li>
                   </ul>
        </text>
      </bodyP>

      <bodyP>
        <text>
          Thank you for your  action. .
        </text>
      </bodyP>


      <bodyP>
        <text>
          <dynamic name="C_D_N" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          C_D_N </dynamic>
        </text>
      </bodyP>


      <textAndImage>
        <text>
          <dynamic name="C_S_N_D" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
           C_S_N_D </dynamic>
        </text>
      </textAndImage>

      <dynamicNames1>
        <dynamicValName>LOW</dynamicValName>
        <dynamicValName>Env</dynamicValName>
      </dynamicNames1>

     </Content>


      Can anyone  provide me with the xsl file which meets my requirement.
```

Comment: Can someone frame an xsl which makes the necessary transformation

Comment: @hroptatyr : Hi, please go through the above question and suggest me the appropriate xsl file.

Comment: @mzjn: yes but facing many issues with one or the other to get the exact transformed output.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev : Hi can you help me in solving the above transformation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Can you suggest me any solution for this question

Comment: @Maestro13 : Hi please suggest a solution.

Comment: I have used some xslt code to achieve this by consulting some experts but unable to get the entire transformation using one xsl file

Comment: @Jeevan: Your wanted output isn't well-formed -- please, correct.

Comment: @Jeevan: You also haven't explained how the namespaces should be changed -- there isn't any "id:d1234" in the properties file -- this means that this string should be hardcoded, or what?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev : hard-code these xsi:schemaLocation="id:d1234    http://abc:10/w/g/B/System/abc.xsd" xmlns="id:d1234" namespaces in xsl file or it would be better if they are also mentioned in properties.xml, so that entire editing(maintainence) part will be only with properties.xml file and our xsl file will have the generalised xslt code. I don't have an idea how the namespaces al mentioned in properties.xml file can be accessed in xsl file. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeevan: Please, edit the question and only provide a small (the smallest possible) XML document for this problem. As stated now, this requires a substantial amount of time, which I and most people will not have. Also, pose a single problem only: is your problem the name substitution, or the namespace substitution? If both, ask separate questions for each of them.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev : its only name substitution, leaving the namespace substitution for time being will hard code them, can you please edit the xsl file that i have edited in the question to achieve the same.

Comment: @Maestro13 : If you see my edited question along with the suggested answer which explains how it can be done,that is what im trying to achieve finally.I think now you would agree for the existence of properties file is a must for our xsl file to access it.But the solution is not completely correct . Need to make changes in it. Can you help me out.

Comment: Hi please help me in solving the above problem.Edit the above answer(xsl file) to get the desired xml file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9912/discussion-between-jeevan-and-dimitre-novatchev)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't need the Properties file as you are only getting rid of namespaces which can be done much simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

The rest of what you want to achieve is probably plain xslt stuff.

**EDIT**

Update including stuff that will get you much closer to your goal

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Content>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Content>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="* [local-name() != 'com' and local-name() != 'content' and local-name() != 'wire' and local-name() != 'sI']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="* [local-name() = 'dynamic']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="* [local-name() = 'contact' or local-name()='dynamicName']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
    <aH>
        <text>Ccc  <dynamic name="C_R_N">C_R_N</dynamic>: More</text>
        <contact>false</contact>
    </aH>
    <page>
        <nL>Please call us</nL>
    </page>
    <body>
        <text> C R N: <strong>
                <dynamic name="C_R_N">C_R_N</dynamic>
            </strong></text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
              RE: <dynamic name="D_C_P">D_C_P</dynamic><dynamic name="M_C_O">M_C_O</dynamic></text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
              In order <strong>
                <dynamic name="M_D_D">M_D_D</dynamic>
            </strong>, we need some information.
            </text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text><strong>
                Please call us <dynamic name="C_P_D_N">C_P_D_N</dynamic>.
              </strong> Our hours <ul class="nested">
                <li>
                   Monday - Friday, 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_S_Hour">DST_M_F_S_Hour</dynamic> am - 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_E_Hour">DST_M_F_E_Hour</dynamic> pm; Saturday, 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_S_Hour">DST_M_F_S_Hour</dynamic> am - 
    <dynamic name="DST_M_F_E_Hour">DST_M_F_E_Hour</dynamic> pm.
                </li>
            </ul></text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
              Thank you for your  action. .
            </text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
            <dynamic name="C_D_N">C_D_N</dynamic>
        </text>
    </body>
    <TextAndImage>
        <text>
            <dynamic name="C_S_N_D">C_S_N_D</dynamic>
        </text>
    </TextAndImage>
    <dynamicNames>
        <dynamicName>LOW</dynamicName>
        <dynamicName>Env</dynamicName>
    </dynamicNames>
</Content>
```

If, instead, you wish to move all attribute values for attributes dynamic/@name and otherElement/@value to the element body, then the following will do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Content>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Content>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="* [local-name() != 'com' and local-name() != 'content' and local-name() != 'wire' and local-name() != 'sI']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="* [local-name() = 'dynamic']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*[local-name !='name']"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="* [local-name() != 'dynamic' and @value]">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*[local-name !='value']"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
    <aH>
        <text>Ccc  <dynamic>C_R_N</dynamic>: More</text>
        <contact>false</contact>
    </aH>
    <page>
        <nL>Please call us</nL>
    </page>
    <body>
        <text> C R N: <strong>
                <dynamic>C_R_N</dynamic>
            </strong></text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
              RE: <dynamic>D_C_P</dynamic><dynamic>M_C_O</dynamic></text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
              In order <strong>
                <dynamic>M_D_D</dynamic>
            </strong>, we need some information.
            </text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text><strong>
                Please call us <dynamic>C_P_D_N</dynamic>.
              </strong> Our hours <ul class="nested">
                <li>
                   Monday - Friday, 
    <dynamic>DST_M_F_S_Hour</dynamic> am - 
    <dynamic>DST_M_F_E_Hour</dynamic> pm; Saturday, 
    <dynamic>DST_M_F_S_Hour</dynamic> am - 
    <dynamic>DST_M_F_E_Hour</dynamic> pm.
                </li>
            </ul></text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
              Thank you for your  action. .
            </text>
    </body>
    <body>
        <text>
            <dynamic>C_D_N</dynamic>
        </text>
    </body>
    <TextAndImage>
        <text>
            <dynamic>C_S_N_D</dynamic>
        </text>
    </TextAndImage>
    <dynamicNames>
        <dynamicName>LOW</dynamicName>
        <dynamicName>Env</dynamicName>
    </dynamicNames>
</Content>
```

Comment: your code doesn't give me the exact output that I am expecting for but yes it is useful and i have tried the same code before.Upon  applying your code on input xml i will get an intermediate xml file on which i have to apply another xsl file to get the desired output. So we end up with two xsl file required for a desired transformed output.

Comment: I am trying to design a single xsl file(generalised one) whose code should not have any hardcoding of input xml element names and if we can achieve this with or without using proerties file is fine with me. And the transformed xml should not contain any namespaces realted to the input xml file and may contain new namespaces. You can refer to the transformed xml file format for reference. Thanks.

Comment: My aim is to generalise the xsl file to any input xml file of that specific format. can you suggest me how can i achieve this, coz if we are hard coding the local tag name  in our xslt code for examples local-name() != 'wire' or local-name() != 'dynamic' i will fail in achieving that. so is there any other alternative for it.

Comment: That depends on what you wish to achieve. From your example I deduced that you want to have the value of dynamic/@name added as element value. If that has to be done for all */@name attribute values then it can be set up more generically. The same holds for other specific templates.

Comment: so if we fail to identify such type of similarity in between the nodes we need to hardcode with their names and proceed with the xslt code inorder to access their content in our desired format right?

Comment: I have tried the same thing identifying the nodes having value attribute tags and try applying your template but its not working

Comment: Can please you provide me a generalised code  for the 'contact' and 'dynamicName' tags which have 'value' attribute in common.

Comment: @Jeevan sorry you lost me - it's unclear to me what your question is. One thing though: when you have a template with `match="*/@value"` and in the template you have `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:element>` then obviously you will get `<value></value>`, because there is no value attribute under the value attribute processed (attributes don't have attributes :-)). So your code is flawed.

Comment: actually i was trying to find all the tags having value attribute.design a common template for them which takes attribute 'value' and place it under respective created tag name.                                                                                                                                        suggest me how can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below xslt code by taking help of the code given by DavidCarlisle which partially fulfill the requirement

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
       xmlns="id:d1234"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
       xmlns:w="http://do.way.com/sales/W" 
       xmlns:wire="http://do.way.com/sales/Wire"    
       exclude-result-prefixes=" wire w ">

         <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
         <xsl:template match="/">
           <Content xsi:schemaLocation="id:d1234 http://abc:10/w/g/B/System/abc.xsd">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="w:sI"/>
          </Content>
        </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="*[local-name()!=sI]">
            <xsl:variable name="n" select="name()"/>
              <xsl:variable name="new">
                <xsl:for-each select="document('Properties.xml')">
                 <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="key('n',$n)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('n',$n)"/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
               </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:element name="{$new}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>


     <xsl:key name="n" match="Property" use="@value"/>

        <xsl:template match="*[name() = 'dynamic']">
            <dynamic xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
               <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                   <strong>
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
             </strong>
           </dynamic>

        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

the only problem im facing in this is i can't comeup with an xslt code which can take the nodes having 'value' attributes (contact and dynamicName) extract its attribute value and put them under respective tag's (specified in Properties.xml) content.
  Please go through this xsl file and make necessary changes in it or I would be equally glad if you can come up with a new one.But please make sure of using Properties.xml file.Thanks.